# RSpec helper specs mock ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm using RSpec for testing. I often find it hard to write good helper specs. Here's an example:

In `app/helper/time_helper.rb` I have the following code:

```
# Returns a text field built with given FormBuilder for given attribute                        |  ~                                                                                                    
# (assumed to be a datetime). The field value is a string representation of                    |  ~                                                                                                    
# the datetime with current TimeZone applied.
def datetime_timezone_field(form_builder, attribute)
  date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
  datetime = form_builder.object.send(attribute)
  form_builder.text_field attribute,
                          value: datetime.in_time_zone.strftime(date_format)
end
```

When testing this, I need to pass a `FormBuilder` to the method. I know how to create the `TestView` but how can I create the `TestModel` used below? In my spec file (spec/helpers/time_helper_spec.rb) I have something like:

```
describe '#datetime_timezone_field' do
  class TestView < ActionView::Base; end

  let(:form_builder) do
    ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder.new(TestModel.model_name.singular,
                                         TestModel.new,
                                         TestView.new,
                                         {})
  end

  it # Some tests here to check the output...
end
```

My problem is `TestModel`. How do I mock such an object? This helper is not connected to a model in my application. `TestModel` should be "any model class" in my app. Or are there better ways of writing the helper method to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually testing the behaviour of the model in anyway, you just need an object that responds to the attribute your passing in.

I'd have thought you could do

```
class TestModel
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :whatever_attribute
end
```

You probably don't need all of `ActiveModel`, but I don't know which parts of it the form builder would expect to have.  You can always look these up.

So essentially you'd then do

```
let(:form_builder) do
    ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder.new(TestModel.model_name.singular,
                                         TestModel.new(whatever_attribute: Time.zone.now),
                                         TestView.new,
                                         {})
end
```

I've not tested this but I don't see any reason it shouldn't work.